# Problem with simply adding elements to the scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on a simple rotating puzzle type game. My question is how best to organize the process so that it would be easier to load different levels of puzzles and add new ones. In theory, I want some puzzle pieces to be larger or smaller than average (as in the picture). I'm new to unity and maybe I don't understand something obvious yet. So I will be glad to any suggestions.

[how puzzle will look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyPtE.png)

The option of throwing puzzles onto the stage and then combining them into a prefab seems simple for further use, but I also don’t want to manually place 100+ puzzle pieces on the stage manually. It would be possible to load elements via a json file, but in this case you would still have to manually enter the coordinates of each puzzle.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  In order to get assistance on this site, you must post the code you have tried and are using, and any errors messages in text format so they can be copy and pasted to offer you support.  Posting of images of code is not allowed, however the picture of the puzzle is fine as it explains what you are trying to do.

Comment: Also another modification to the question that will help you would be that you need to focus the question, asking "how to make a game" is too many steps.  Asking "How to paste an object to the screen" is a focused question.  After that step if you need more, ask the following question as a seperate post until you get all the answer you need.

Comment: surely you have a prefab of a tile, you spawn it x times, you then split any given picture up into x-1 peices, and then plop them on the tiles, you then shuffle them using code magic, and then present the user with the need to sort it out.

Comment: If you have puzzle pieces of different sizes, how do you expect to rearrange them? Theres a reason all puzzle games have tiles the same size.